# Vector equilibrium point(s) function in C++

Tags: c++, vector

So I wanted to clean the rust off my C++ skills and thought I'd start with something fairly simple. An equilibrium point in a vector A of size N is a point K, such that: A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[K−1] = A[K+1] + ... + A[N−2] + A[N−1]. The rationale behind the function algorithm is simple: Check each consecutive element of the vector and compare the sum of the elements before said element with the sum of the elements after it and if they are equal, output the index of that element. While it sounds simple (and I imagine that it is) it turned out to be harder to implement in reality. Here's what the code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void EquilibriumPoint(std::vector<int> &A);
void VectorPrint(std::vector<int> &V);

void main()
{
    int input;
    std::vector<int> Vect1;
    cout << "Input the vector elements" << endl;
    while (cin >> input)
       Vect1.push_back(input);
    VectorPrint(Vect1);
    EquilibriumPoint(Vect1);
}

void EquilibriumPoint(std::vector<int> &A)
{

    for (int it = 0; it != A.size(); ++it)
    {
        int lowersum = 0;
        int uppersum = 0;
        for (int beg = 0; beg != it; ++beg) lowersum += A[beg];
        for (int end = it + 1; end != A.size(); ++end) uppersum += A[end];
        if (uppersum == lowersum) cout << it;
    }
}

void VectorPrint(std::vector<int> &V)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != V.size(); ++i)
        cout << V[i] << endl;
}
```

As you can see I threw in a print function also for good measure. The problem is that the program doesn't seem to execute the EquilibriumPoint function. There must be a problem with the logic of the implementation but I can't find it. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to execute it or it does not execute it? have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Not the immediate problem but FWIW (a) `void main` is nasty, (b) the parameters you're passing to your two functions should be `const` and (c) your algorithm is O(n^2), whereas it's quite easy to do this in O(n).

Comment: Also, you should de-couple the input from the problem. If you want to test an algorithm, instantiate a vector with a bunch of numbers instead of using `cin`.

Comment: @UnholySheep no I haven't, how do I do that in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: @PaulR
a)Why is void main nasty? 
b)Why? 
c)I'm not familiar with the Big O notation yet, but thanks for the reminder to actually check it out. As far as complexity and efficiency go, I know this is probably the worst way to do this but I thought I'd start out with something basic and work my way toward something better.

Comment: In VS you first need to place a breakpoint (left click to the left of the line of code where you want to break, a red dot should appear) and then start the program in the debugger (either in the standard setting by clicking the green arrow or F5 key) - the program then stops at the breakpoint and you can step through line by line and look at what values are stored your variables (and even look at disassembled code if you wish)

Comment: @AutomEng; (a) `main` should always return an `int` status to the operating system (0 for success), (b) using `const` is important for robustness (helps to prevent unintended modification of data that shouldn't be modified), efficiency (allows certain compiler optimisations) and furthermore it helps to make the code more self-documenting (e.g. shows which parameters are input-only).

Comment: @PaulR as for point (a) I was under the impression that declaring main to be void was a way to do exactly what you described "by default". As for (b), thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: @AutomEng: no, it's just a bad habit that seems to have taken hold due to some very bad C books and sloppy teaching at certain colleges, compounded by the fact that you can get away with it on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin >> input
```

always returns true for you - so IMHO you have an endless loop. You need to stop collecting elements at some point, for instance

```
int input = 1
while (input)
{
    cin >> input;
    Vect1.push_back(input);
}
```

Will accept all elements that are not zero, when zero arrives, it will end the vector and run your function.

Or you can first input the number of elements (if you want to include zeros), example:

```
int count;
cin >> count
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
  cin >> input;
  Vect1.push_back(input);
}
```

I didn't check the rest of the code, though. One problem at a time.

Comment: The OP's input method is fine so long as the user knows to signal EOF when they're done (i.e. Control-D in most sensible operating systems, or Control-Z in Windows).

Comment: Indeed. Then the program works just fine. Everyday is a school day.